# JTextArea on JScrollPane not appearing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm writing a program that's supposed to print text. I need it to be on a `JScrollPane` and I also need to be able to go to the next page of text by clicking on a next page button.

The only way I can get any text to show up is by adding the text directly to the pane. (line 91 `ctPanel.add(bText);`)

```
public class RP extends JPanel{

private Border simpleBorder;
private JPanel iPanel;
private JPanel ctPanel;
private JPanel nPanel;
private JLabel T; 
private JLabel A;
private JLabel P;
private JButton upButton;
private JButton downButton;
public JTextArea bText;
private JScrollPane Scroll;
private String placeholder;

public RP()
{

this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720,700));

simpleBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
//this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(simpleBorder, "R"));
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// start of i panel:

placeholder = new String("nothing right now");

iPanel = new JPanel();
this.add(iPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
iPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(simpleBorder, "I"));

T = new JLabel();
T.setText("T: " + placeholder);
iPanel.add(T, BorderLayout.WEST);

A = new JLabel();
A.setText("B: " + placeholder);
iPanel.add(A, BorderLayout.CENTER);

P = new JLabel();
P.setText("P: " + placeholder);
iPanel.add(P, BorderLayout.EAST);


// start of ct panel (RP -> Ct Panel):

ctPanel = new JPanel();
ctPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(simpleBorder, "C"));
ctPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



// Create JScrollPane and add it to Ct Panel
Scroll = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);



// create btext area
bText = new JTextArea();
bText.setEditable(false);
bText.setText("Nothing right now.");

//add text to scroll pane
Scroll.add(bText);



//add scroll pane to ct panel
ctPanel.add(Scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);




//add ct panel to RP
ctPanel.add(bText); // IF I COMMENT THIS OUT, THE TEXT WON'T APPEAR IN THE 
CONTENT PANEL
this.add(ctPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// start of navigation panel:

nPanel = new JPanel();
this.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
nPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(simpleBorder,"Navigation") 
);

upButton = new JButton();
upButton.setText("Up");
nPanel.add(upButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

downButton = new JButton();
downButton.setText("Down");
nPanel.add(downButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

// revalidate and repaint:  
this.revalidate();
this.repaint(); 
}       


// method to set text in bText JTextField from another class
public void setBText(String text)
{
bText.setText(text);
}

// method to set T info to i panel from another class
public void setTInfo(String text)
{
T.setText("T: " + text);
}

// method to set A info to i panel from another class
public void setAInfo(String text)
{
A.setText("B " + text);
}

}
```

Comment: *"Any help is appreciated.."* What is the question? General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) `bText = new JTextArea();` should be more like `bText = new JTextArea(20,4); // suggest a size` ..

Comment: 5) `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720,700));` This is just a guess. Remove it and instead `pack()` the top level window once all components are added. The panel will end up the smallest size it needs to be in order to display the components it contains (and their borders and padding as coded). 6) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you! This was my first post, so I felt pretty unsure about how to do it properly. My main problem was that I couldn't get bText to show up on the JScrollPane. The suggestion from camickr to use the .setViewportView did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

```
Scroll.add(bText);
```

Don't add components to the scroll pane directly. Components are added to the `viewport` of the scroll pane using;

```
//Scroll.add(bText);
scroll.setViewportView( bText );
```

Also a component can only be added to a single component. So get rid of:

```
//ctPanel.add(bText);
```

since you already added the text area to the viewport of the scroll pane.

Comment: Thank you! Using scroll.setViewportView(bText) fixed it.